# legend in ggplot2 not appropriately displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I am trying to add text label to my ggplot graph, but I am getting a weird legend. Here is the example:

I have 2 data frames as below, I want to highlight gene `a` from both the data frames. Below is my code:

```
control <- read.table(text = "genename  fc  p-val   q-val   type
a   0.4 0.0034  0.031   con
b   2   0.0005  0.01    con", header = T,sep="\t")

treatment <- read.table(text = "genename    fc  p-val   q-val   type
a   0.6 0.002   0.01    treat
c   1.5 0.000066    0.004   treat", header =T, sep="\t")


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(control,aes(x = log2(fc),
                   y = -log10(q.val), 
                   color = type))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = subset(control, genename == "a"),
            aes(label = genename, vjust = 2)) +
  geom_point(data = treatment) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(treatment, genename == "a"),
            aes(label = genename, vjust = 2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("con" = "blue",
                                "treat" = "red"))
```

and here is the image which has a weird legend:

[image: image_legend]

The legend should have round shape rather than what we see here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `show.legend = FALSE` inside `geom_text`

Comment: that worked!!, can you explain what happened here?

Comment: show.legend 
logical. Should this layer be included in the legends? NA, the default, includes if any aesthetics are mapped. FALSE never includes, and TRUE always includes. It can also be a named logical vector to finely select the aesthetics to display.

Comment: You defined the aesthetic `col` globally inside `ggplot`, so it will apply to every `geom_` layer

Comment: Any better way to code this?

Comment: You could just set `color = type` inside geom_point

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way: put all the data in one data frame. Now you can use the `type` column for the color aesthetic inside `geom_point`, and `filter` the data for `geom_text`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

control <- read.table(text = "genename  fc  p-val   q-val   type
a   0.4 0.0034  0.031   con
b   2   0.0005  0.01    con", header = TRUE)

treatment <- read.table(text = "genename    fc  p-val   q-val   type
a   0.6 0.002   0.01    treat
c   1.5 0.000066    0.004   treat", header = TRUE)

combined <- bind_rows(control, treatment)

combined %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = log2(fc),
               y = -log10(q.val))) +
    geom_point(aes(color = type)) + 
    geom_text(data = filter(combined, genename == "a"), 
              aes(label = genename), vjust = 2)
```

Result:

[image]

Data:

```
combined <- structure(list(genename = c("a", "b", "a", "c"), fc = c(0.4, 
2, 0.6, 1.5), p.val = c(0.0034, 5e-04, 0.002, 6.6e-05), q.val = c(0.031, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.004), type = c("con", "con", "treat", "treat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I just want to highlight `a` from both the data frames and hence I did not combine the data frames

Comment: OK, so then you can `filter` the data. Answer edited. Data in one data frame is generally a better way to use `ggplot`.